# How to fix discord XML file issue?

Tags: xml, discord

```
<Error> 
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to discord/app.</Details>
</Error>
```

I have tried uninstalling, restarting, and nothing on google says anything about this. All the posts iv'e seen are about images or whatever but literally this is all i see when i boot up disord. Can't do anything. :/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! One way to improve formatting is to use indentation (4 spaces for each level) and new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Discord folder and will get this.
[Discord folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5pdj.png)

Then open the app-0.0.305 folder or the app-0.0.306. Then run the Discord.exe.
[The **app-0.0.305** or **app-0.0.306** folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiNHq.png)

That worked for me.